# Storing time series ranges in ElasticSearch and using aggregations

Tags: database, mongodb, elasticsearch, time-series

We have a data which consist of a from and to timestamp and a value. For example from : `2021-12-18-10:10:00` to: `2021-12-18-10:15:00` steps: `10`. I am wondering what is the best way to store and query that data. We would like to generate aggregates of those - such as how many steps has the user done in a day, or what were the most active hours for the user this month etc. We are currently using MongoDB and we are exploring the MongoDB time series capabilities. However I am also interested if elastic search would be suitable for that and if you can point me to some examples that I can start with. Be aware the date doesn't have a single timestamp it has from and to ?

Comment: Were you able to find more information? MongoDB docs are really bad still for this feature.